# How to have sbt multi-project builds configure setting for subprojects?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbteclipse

I have an [sbt](/questions/tagged/sbt) (0.13.1) project with a bunch of subprojects.  I am generating [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) project configurations using [sbteclipse](/questions/tagged/sbteclipse).  My projects only have [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) source files, so I want to remove the generated src/java folders.

I can achieve that by (redundantly) adding the following to the build.sbt of each subproject:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := (scalaSource in Compile).value :: Nil

unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test := (scalaSource in Test).value :: Nil
```

I tried just adding the above configuration to the root build.sbt but the `eclipse` command still generated the java source folders.

Is there any way to specify a configuration like this once (in the root build.sbt) and have it flow down to each subproject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the settings unscoped and then reuse them

```
val onlyScalaSources = Seq(
  unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := Seq((scalaSource in Compile).value),
  unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test := Seq((scalaSource in Test).value)
)

val project1 = project.in( file( "project1" )
  .settings(onlyScalaSources: _*)

val project2 = project.in( file( "project2" )
  .settings(onlyScalaSources: _*)
```

You could also create a simple plugin (untested code)

```
object OnlyScalaSources extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = allRequirements
  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := Seq((scalaSource in Compile).value),
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test := Seq((scalaSource in Test).value)
  )
}
```

More details about creating plugins in the [plugins documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html)