# SBT multiproject setup where a subproject's build files depend on unmanaged JARs

Tags: scala, sbt, build-system

Scenario:

- I want to develop a projectA written in Scala, which depends on projectB, also written in Scala.
- It will often be the case that I need to modify projectB as well. Hence, I will have a local Git clone of projectB (as in [my repository](https://github.com/ComFreek/sbt-multi-project-question) as a submodule).
- Now projectA should pull the dependency on projectB directly from that cloned Git repository of projectB.

I now have the following setup, which is also available at GitHub: https://github.com/ComFreek/sbt-multi-project-question

```
| - .git
|
| - projectA
| | - src
| | - build.sbt
|
| - projectB (Git submodule)
| | - src
| | | - build.sbt
| | | - project
| | | - project.sbt
| | | - ...
```

In `projectA/build.sbt` tried:

```scala
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / ".." / "projectB" / "deploy" / "lib"

lazy val projectB = RootProject(file("../projectB/src/project"))

lazy val projectA = Project(id = "projectA", base = file(".")).settings(
  name := "projectA",
  version := "0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
  scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
).dependsOn(projectB)
```

However, it seems that [`projectB/src/build.sbt`](https://github.com/UniFormal/MMT/blob/b558245d2ea927ceb699edfdee7a18d51fe96955/src/build.sbt#L118) uses unmanaged libraries put into [`projectB/deploy/lib`](https://github.com/UniFormal/MMT/tree/b558245d2ea927ceb699edfdee7a18d51fe96955/deploy/lib) which cannot be found when `sbt compile` is run from within the scope of projectA - even with the `unmanagedBase` property set.

Concretely, you can reproduce it as follows:

1. Open an SBT shell in `projectA`
2. Run `compile` and get

   ```
   [IJ]sbt:projectA> compile
   [info] Compiling 13 Scala sources to ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\target\scala-2.12\classes ...
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\File.scala:19:11: object tools is not a member of package scala
   [error]     scala.tools.nsc.io.File(f.toString).appendAll(strings:_*)
   [error]           ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\Utils.scala:31:14: object Keys is not a member of package sbt
   [error]   import sbt.Keys.packageBin
   [error]              ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\Utils.scala:33:36: not found: value Def
   [error]   def deployPackage(name: String): Def.Initialize[Task[Unit]] =
   [error]                                    ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\Utils.scala:34:5: not found: value packageBin
   [error]     packageBin in Compile map {jar => deployTo(Utils.deploy / name)(jar)}
   [error]     ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\Utils.scala:34:19: not found: value Compile
   [error]     packageBin in Compile map {jar => deployTo(Utils.deploy / name)(jar)}
   [error]                   ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\Utils.scala:45:39: type File is not a member of package sbt
   [error]   def deployTo(target: File)(jar: sbt.File): Unit = {
   [error]                                       ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\Utils.scala:39:36: not found: value Def
   [error]   def deployMathHub(target: File): Def.Initialize[Task[Unit]] =
   [error]                                    ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\Utils.scala:40:5: not found: value packageBin
   [error]     packageBin in Compile map {jar => deployTo(target)(jar)}
   [error]     ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\Utils.scala:40:19: not found: value Compile
   [error]     packageBin in Compile map {jar => deployTo(target)(jar)}
   [error]                   ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\Utils.scala:123:25: not found: type Logger
   [error]   def delRecursive(log: Logger, path: File): Unit = {
   [error]                         ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:8:44: not found: type Project
   [error] case class VersionSpecificProject(project: Project, excludes: Exclusions) {
   [error]                                            ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:13:48: not found: type Project
   [error]   def aggregate(projects: ProjectReference*) : Project = project.aggregate(excludes(projects.toList) :_*)
   [error]                                                ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:13:27: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def aggregate(projects: ProjectReference*) : Project = project.aggregate(excludes(projects.toList) :_*)
   [error]                           ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:17:48: not found: type Project
   [error]   def dependsOn(projects: ProjectReference*) : Project = {
   [error]                                                ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:17:27: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def dependsOn(projects: ProjectReference*) : Project = {
   [error]                           ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:18:47: not found: type ClasspathDep
   [error]     def toClassPathDep(p: ProjectReference) : ClasspathDep[ProjectReference] = p
   [error]                                               ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:18:27: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]     def toClassPathDep(p: ProjectReference) : ClasspathDep[ProjectReference] = p
   [error]                           ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:23:59: not found: type Project
   [error]   def aggregatesAndDepends(projects: ProjectReference*) : Project = {
   [error]                                                           ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:23:38: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def aggregatesAndDepends(projects: ProjectReference*) : Project = {
   [error]                                      ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:24:47: not found: type ClasspathDep
   [error]     def toClassPathDep(p: ProjectReference) : ClasspathDep[ProjectReference] = p
   [error]                                               ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:24:27: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]     def toClassPathDep(p: ProjectReference) : ClasspathDep[ProjectReference] = p
   [error]                           ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:30:37: not found: type Project
   [error]   implicit def fromProject(project: Project) : VersionSpecificProject = VersionSpecificProject(project, Exclusions())
   [error]                                     ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:34:28: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error] case class Exclusions(lst: ProjectReference*) {
   [error]                            ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:31:61: not found: type Project
   [error]   implicit def toProject(vProject: VersionSpecificProject): Project = vProject.project
   [error]                                                             ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:35:68: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   private def javaVersion(versions: List[String], exclusions: List[ProjectReference]) : Exclusions = {
   [error]                                                                    ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:43:22: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def :::(lst2: List[ProjectReference]) = Exclusions(lst.toList ::: lst2 : _*)
   [error]                      ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:39:25: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def java7(exclusions: ProjectReference*): Exclusions = javaVersion(List("1.7", "7"), exclusions.toList)
   [error]                         ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:40:25: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def java8(exclusions: ProjectReference*): Exclusions = javaVersion(List("1.8", "8"), exclusions.toList)
   [error]                         ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:41:25: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def java9(exclusions: ProjectReference*): Exclusions = javaVersion(List("1.9", "9"), exclusions.toList)
   [error]                         ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:46:18: not found: value ScopeFilter
   [error]   def toFilter : ScopeFilter.ProjectFilter = {
   [error]                  ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:47:5: not found: value inAnyProject
   [error]     inAnyProject -- inProjects(lst :_*)
   [error]     ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:47:21: not found: value inProjects
   [error]     inAnyProject -- inProjects(lst :_*)
   [error]                     ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:51:28: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   private def equals(left: ProjectReference, right: ProjectReference) : Boolean = {
   [error]                            ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:51:53: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   private def equals(left: ProjectReference, right: ProjectReference) : Boolean = {
   [error]                                                     ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:61:25: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def excludes(project: ProjectReference) : Boolean = lst.exists(equals(_, project))
   [error]                         ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:62:54: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def apply(projects: List[ProjectReference]) : List[ProjectReference] = projects.filterNot(this.excludes)
   [error]                                                      ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:62:28: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def apply(projects: List[ProjectReference]) : List[ProjectReference] = projects.filterNot(this.excludes)
   [error]                            ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:64:17: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def map[B](f: ProjectReference => B) : Seq[B] = lst.map(f)
   [error]                 ^
   [error] ...\sbt-multi-project-question\projectB\src\project\VersionSpecificProject.scala:65:21: not found: type ProjectReference
   [error]   def foreach[U](f: ProjectReference => U) : Exclusions = {lst.foreach[U](f); this }
   [error]                     ^
   [error] 39 errors found
   [error] (ProjectRef(uri("file:/.../sbt-multi-project-question/projectB/src/project/"), "project") / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
   [error] Total time: 5 s, completed 04.03.2019, 10:10:34
   [IJ]sbt:projectA>
   ```

However, the following works:

1. Open an SBT shell in `projectB/src`.
2. Run `compile`
   Beware that it takes ~12 minutes on my machine and outputs a lot of warnings, but no errors.

**Research.** There are some resources explaining how to share unmanaged libraries between subprojects (e.g. 1 and 2 below), but none them seem to face the issue that the *build setup* (not only the code!) also depends on those unmanaged libraries.

1. [How to inherit unmanaged dependencies in submodules in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23919388/603003)
2. [How to have sbt multi-project builds configure setting for subprojects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26809331/603003))

Comment: does your setup work if you don't have any unmanaged dependencies?

Comment: @pme I am not sure, I guess it would require a lot of work to pull out those unmanaged dependencies without modifying the dependency project's build setup too heavily.

Comment: Did you found the solution already on this project @ComFreek?

Comment: @Rex Not yet, currently, I am testing out [pme's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55077913/603003) suggestion, see the comments there.

Comment: Ahh i see. but I think everything they suggest are good answers.
This are the most important keyword  here `.aggregate()`  and `.dependsOn()`

Comment: @Rex If you're interested, thirstycrow has posted [a working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55107829/603003).

Comment: Could you please also suggest your valuable inputs for below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084177/uber-jar-with-custom-folder-structure-with-intellij-and-sbt/63091787#63091787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to compile the projects with the following changes.

First, I got compilation errors when trying to compile the projectB @ b558245 revision, which is referenced in your GitHub project. I checked the latest tag, v15.0.0, and it compiled.

Second, in `projectA/build.sbt`, `projectB` should be defined as

```
lazy val projectB = RootProject(file("../projectB/src"))
```

`../projectB/src/project` is the builder project that builds projectB. It requires things in scala compiler and sbt, and thus produced the errors you saw when you tried to compile it directly.

Third, `projectB` failed to compile as a dependency of `projectA`. That's because, the `Utils` object (in `projectB/src/project/Utils.scala`) which was intended to refer to the layout of `projectB`, was initialized with a wrong directory (`../projectA`)

```
object Utils {
   /** MMT root directory */
   val root = File("..").canonical  // Got the wrong directory when compiled with projectA
```

So, we have to do some modifications to `Utils.scala` and it dependents, to ensure it always find the right position of `projectB`. Here is the patch to `projectB` to make it compile from `projectA`. Might not be the best solution, but it works on my laptop.

```
diff --git a/src/build.sbt b/src/build.sbt
index 059ef9c8e..b7495c8eb 100644
--- a/src/build.sbt
+++ b/src/build.sbt
@@ -1,10 +1,13 @@
 import scala.io.Source
 import sbt.Keys._
+import Utils.utils
+
+utils in ThisBuild := Utils((baseDirectory in src).value)

 // =================================
 // META-DATA and Versioning
 // =================================
-version in ThisBuild := {Source.fromFile("mmt-api/resources/versioning/system.txt").getLines.mkString.trim}
+version in ThisBuild := {Source.fromFile(baseDirectory.value / "mmt-api/resources/versioning/system.txt").getLines.mkString.trim}

 val now = {
   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
@@ -106,7 +109,7 @@ def mmtProjectsSettings(nameStr: String) = commonSettings(nameStr) ++ Seq(

   unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value  / "lib",

-  publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", Utils.deploy.toJava / " main")),
+  publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", utils.value.deploy.toJava / " main")),

   install := {},
   deploy := Utils.deployPackage("main/" + nameStr + ".jar").value
@@ -153,8 +156,12 @@ lazy val mmt = (project in file("mmt")).
   settings(
     exportJars := false,
     publish := {},
-    deploy := {
-      assembly in Compile map Utils.deployTo(Utils.deploy / "mmt.jar")
+    deploy := Def.taskDyn {
+      val jar = (assembly in Compile).value
+      val u = utils.value
+      Def.task {
+        Utils.deployTo(u.deploy / "mmt.jar")(jar)
+      }
     }.value,
     assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {
       val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
@@ -172,13 +179,13 @@ lazy val mmt = (project in file("mmt")).

 // MMT is split into multiple subprojects to that are managed independently.

-val apiJars = Seq(
+def apiJars(u: Utils) = Seq(
   "scala-compiler.jar",
   "scala-reflect.jar",
   "scala-parser-combinators.jar",
   "scala-xml.jar",
   "xz.jar",
-).map(Utils.lib.toJava / _ )
+).map(u.lib.toJava / _ )

 // The kernel upon which everything else depends. Maintainer: Florian
 lazy val api = (project in file("mmt-api")).
@@ -188,8 +195,8 @@ lazy val api = (project in file("mmt-api")).
   settings(
     scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-language:existentials"),
     scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main",
-    unmanagedJars in Compile ++= apiJars,
-    unmanagedJars in Test ++= apiJars,
+    unmanagedJars in Compile ++= apiJars(utils.value),
+    unmanagedJars in Test ++= apiJars(utils.value),
   )


@@ -226,7 +233,7 @@ lazy val jedit = (project in file("jEdit-mmt")).
     resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src/resources",
     unmanagedJars in Compile ++= jeditJars map (baseDirectory.value / "lib" / _),
     deploy := Utils.deployPackage("main/MMTPlugin.jar").value,
-    install := Utils.installJEditJars
+    install := utils.value.installJEditJars
   )

 // MMT IntelliJ-Plugin. Maintainer: Dennis
@@ -299,7 +306,7 @@ lazy val concepts = (project in file("concept-browser")).
     libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup" % "tagsoup" % "1.2"
     ),
-    unmanagedJars in Compile += Utils.lib.toJava / "scala-xml.jar"
+    unmanagedJars in Compile += utils.value.lib.toJava / "scala-xml.jar"
  )

 // =================================
@@ -389,7 +396,7 @@ lazy val oeis = (project in file("mmt-oeis")).
   dependsOn(planetary).
   settings(mmtProjectsSettings("mmt-oeis"): _*).
   settings(
-    unmanagedJars in Compile += Utils.lib.toJava / "scala-parser-combinators.jar"
+    unmanagedJars in Compile += utils.value.lib.toJava / "scala-parser-combinators.jar"
   )

 // =================================
@@ -416,11 +423,15 @@ lazy val lfcatalog = (project in file("lfcatalog")).
   settings(commonSettings("lfcatalog")).
   settings(
     scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src",
-    publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", Utils.deploy.toJava / " main")),
-    deployLFCatalog := {
-      assembly in Compile map Utils.deployTo(Utils.deploy / "lfcatalog" / "lfcatalog.jar")
+    publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", utils.value.deploy.toJava / " main")),
+    deployLFCatalog := Def.taskDyn {
+      val jar = (assembly in Compile).value
+      val u = utils.value
+      Def.task {
+        Utils.deployTo(u.deploy / "lfcatalog" / "lfcatalog.jar")(jar)
+      }
     }.value,
-    unmanagedJars in Compile += Utils.lib.toJava / "scala-xml.jar"
+    unmanagedJars in Compile += utils.value.lib.toJava / "scala-xml.jar"
   )

 // =================================
diff --git a/src/project/Utils.scala b/src/project/Utils.scala
index 2f9b94fd4..8f862666e 100644
--- a/src/project/Utils.scala
+++ b/src/project/Utils.scala
@@ -1,9 +1,84 @@
 import java.nio.file.Files
 import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption._
+import sbt.Keys.packageBin
+import sbt._

 object Utils {
+
+  val utils = settingKey[Utils]("Utils")
+
+  def apply(base: java.io.File) = new Utils(File(base))
+
+  def error(s: String) = throw new Exception(s)
+
+  // ************************************************** deploy-specific code (see also the TaskKey's deploy and deployFull)
+
+  /*
+   * copies files to deploy folder
+   */
+  def deployTo(target: File)(jar: sbt.File): Unit = {
+    Files.copy(jar.toPath, target.toPath, REPLACE_EXISTING)
+    println("copied file: " + jar)
+    println("to file: " + target)
+  }
+
+  /**
+    * packages the compiled binaries and copies to deploy
+    */
+  def deployPackage(name: String) : Def.Initialize[Task[Unit]] = Def.taskDyn {
+    val j = (packageBin in Compile).value
+    val u = utils.value
+    Def.task {
+      deployTo(u.deploy / name)(j)
+    }
+  }
+
+  /**
+    * packages the compiled binaries and copies to deploy
+    */
+  def deployMathHub(target: File): Def.Initialize[Task[Unit]] =
+    packageBin in Compile map {jar => deployTo(target)(jar)}
+
+  // ************************************************** file system utilities
+
+  /** copy a file */
+  def copy(from: File, to: File) {
+    println(s"copying $from to $to")
+    if (!from.exists) {
+      error(s"error: file $from not found (when trying to copy it to $to)")
+    } else if (!to.exists || from.lastModified > to.lastModified) {
+      Files.copy(from.toPath, to.toPath, REPLACE_EXISTING)
+    } else {
+      println("skipped (up-to-date)")
+    }
+    println("\n")
+  }
+
+  /**
+    * Recursively deletes a given folder
+    * @param log
+    * @param path
+    */
+  def delRecursive(log: Logger, path: File): Unit = {
+    def delRecursive(path: File): Unit = {
+      path.listFiles foreach { f =>
+        if (f.isDirectory) delRecursive(f)
+        else {
+          f.delete()
+          log.debug("deleted file: " + path)
+        }
+      }
+      path.delete()
+      log.debug("deleted directory: " + path)
+    }
+    if (path.exists && path.isDirectory) delRecursive(path)
+    else log.warn("ignoring missing directory: " + path)
+  }
+}
+
+class Utils(base: File) {
    /** MMT root directory */
-   val root = File("..").canonical
+   val root = (base / "..").canonical
    /** source folder */
    val src = root / "src"
    /** MMT deploy directory */
@@ -21,33 +96,6 @@ object Utils {
    /** executes a shell command (in the src folder) */
    def runscript(command: String) = sys.process.Process(Seq(command), src.getAbsoluteFile).!!

-   def error(s: String) = throw new Exception(s)
-
-  // ************************************************** deploy-specific code (see also the TaskKey's deploy and deployFull)
-
- /**
-   * packages the compiled binaries and copies to deploy
-   */
-  import sbt.Keys.packageBin
-  import sbt._
-  def deployPackage(name: String): Def.Initialize[Task[Unit]] =
-    packageBin in Compile map {jar => deployTo(Utils.deploy / name)(jar)}
-
- /**
-   * packages the compiled binaries and copies to deploy
-   */
-  def deployMathHub(target: File): Def.Initialize[Task[Unit]] =
-    packageBin in Compile map {jar => deployTo(target)(jar)}
-
-  /*
-   * copies files to deploy folder
-   */
-  def deployTo(target: File)(jar: sbt.File): Unit = {
-    Files.copy(jar.toPath, target.toPath, REPLACE_EXISTING)
-    println("copied file: " + jar)
-    println("to file: " + target)
-  }
-

   // ************************************************** MathHub-specific code

@@ -79,7 +127,7 @@ object Utils {
       settings.get(killJEdit).foreach {x => runscript(x)}
      Thread.sleep(500)
       val fname = settings.get(jeditSettingsFolder).getOrElse {
-        error(s"cannot copy jars because there is no setting '$jeditSettingsFolder' in $settingsFile")
+        Utils.error(s"cannot copy jars because there is no setting '$jeditSettingsFolder' in $settingsFile")
         return
       }
       val jsf = File(fname) / "jars"
@@ -92,47 +140,10 @@ object Utils {
    }
    /** copy all jEdit jars to a directory */
    def copyJEditJars(to: File) {
-      copy(deploy/"mmt.jar", to/"MMTPlugin.jar")
+      Utils.copy(deploy/"mmt.jar", to/"MMTPlugin.jar")
       // all other jars are bundled with the above
       // val jEditDeps = List("scala-library.jar","scala-parser-combinators.jar","scala-reflect.jar","scala-xml.jar","tiscaf.jar")
       // jEditDeps.foreach {f => copy(deploy/"lib"/f, to/f)}
       // copy(deploy/"lfcatalog"/"lfcatalog.jar", to/"lfcatalog.jar")
    }
-
-
-  // ************************************************** file system utilities
-
-   /** copy a file */
-   def copy(from: File, to: File) {
-      println(s"copying $from to $to")
-      if (!from.exists) {
-         error(s"error: file $from not found (when trying to copy it to $to)")
-      } else if (!to.exists || from.lastModified > to.lastModified) {
-         Files.copy(from.toPath, to.toPath, REPLACE_EXISTING)
-      } else {
-         println("skipped (up-to-date)")
-      }
-      println("\n")
-   }
-
-  /**
-    * Recursively deletes a given folder
-    * @param log
-    * @param path
-    */
-  def delRecursive(log: Logger, path: File): Unit = {
-    def delRecursive(path: File): Unit = {
-      path.listFiles foreach { f =>
-        if (f.isDirectory) delRecursive(f)
-        else {
-          f.delete()
-          log.debug("deleted file: " + path)
-        }
-      }
-      path.delete()
-      log.debug("deleted directory: " + path)
-    }
-    if (path.exists && path.isDirectory) delRecursive(path)
-    else log.warn("ignoring missing directory: " + path)
-  }
 }
diff --git a/src/project/build.properties b/src/project/build.properties
index 9f782f704..1fc4b8093 100644
--- a/src/project/build.properties
+++ b/src/project/build.properties
@@ -1 +1 @@
-sbt.version=1.1.1
\ No newline at end of file
+sbt.version=1.2.8
\ No newline at end of file
diff --git a/src/travis.sbt b/src/travis.sbt
index 88fb446d3..a71be9d2e 100644
--- a/src/travis.sbt
+++ b/src/travis.sbt
@@ -2,6 +2,7 @@ import sbt._
 import sbt.Keys._
 import travis.Matrix._
 import travis.Config._
+import Utils.utils

 import scala.io.Source

@@ -86,11 +87,11 @@ travisConfig := {
 val genTravisYML = taskKey[Unit]("Print out travis.yml configuration")
 genTravisYML := {
   // read the prefix and the config
-  val prefix = Source.fromFile(Utils.src / "project" / "prefix.travis.yml").getLines.filter(!_.startsWith("##")).mkString("\n")
+  val prefix = Source.fromFile(utils.value.src / "project" / "prefix.travis.yml").getLines.filter(!_.startsWith("##")).mkString("\n")
   val config = travisConfig.value.serialize

   // and write it into .travis.yml
-  val outFile = Utils.root / ".travis.yml"
+  val outFile = utils.value.root / ".travis.yml"
   IO.write(outFile, prefix + "\n" + config)
   streams.value.log.info(s"Wrote $outFile")
 }
```

Comment: **Thank you so much! Works great! The part on the wrong relative directory was spot on!** PS: I had to apply your Git patch manually since the whitespace on empty lines had been stripped by StackOverflow. I'll post an online Git-diff from GitHub once the changes are merged. Anyhow, I don't think any future visitor will care about every tiny change, just that one has to use `baseDirectory.value`.

Comment: Git diff: https://github.com/UniFormal/MMT/commit/5a34899098d6cb0558b46573e504f5f8104fb434

Comment: Sorry to be a help vampire! Do you know how to run tasks of `projectB` from the SBT shell of `projectA`? E.g. `projectB` declares the task `deploy` in its subproject `mmt`, hence `mmt/deploy` normally works from within `projectB`, but not from `projectA` ("Not a valid command: mmt"). Changing projects also doesn't work: `project mmt` tells me it can't find the project even though `projects` list it.

Comment: Oh wait, having `).dependsOn(projectB).aggregates(projectB)` in `projectA`'s `build.sbt` at least allows me to run `deploy`. Let's wait until that finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok with these changes in `build.sbt` it works on my machine:

```
//unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / ".." / "projectB" / "deploy" / "lib"
// this only defines the unmanagedBase of Project A


//lazy val projectB = RootProject(file("../projectB/src/project"))
// see the project setup below
lazy val projectB = RootProject(file("../projectB"))  
lazy val projectBmmt = RootProject(file("../projectB/mmt"))

lazy val projectA = Project(id = "projectA", base = file(".")).settings(
  name := "projectA",
  version := "0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
  scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation"),
 // unmanagedBase in ThisBuild := baseDirectory.value / ".." / "projectB" / "deploy" / "lib"
 // this only defines the unmanagedBase of Project A
).dependsOn(projectB, projectBmmt)
```

Here my file setup:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now the SBT build setup is loaded just fine, however, it seems that the subprojects of projectB do not get put into scope in projectA. E.g. projectB defines in `src/mmt-api/src` some API which I cannot import in projectA: https://pastebin.com/Asa4j59R.

Comment: I already tried specifying another project `lazy val mmtApi = RootProject(file("../mmt/src/mmt-api"))` to depend on via `).dependsOn(projectB, mmtApi)`, but that fails with the same error messages, namely that the imports cannot be found (during compilation).

Comment: what you can try to add the submodule as well - I adjusted my response - but I haven't tried that

Comment: That's what I tried. The path is `file("../projectB/src/mmt-api")`, though. Sorry if I confuse projectB and "MMT" from time to time. Both refer to the same project `../projectB`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think my first answer hit a dead-end;(.

Here a total new idea:

Add your project (projectA) as a submodule of projectB.

This is the structure:

[image]

The `build.sbt` from `projectB` needs a small adjustment:

```
// added for my project 
lazy val projectA = (project in file("projectA")).
  dependsOn(api)
```

If you can handle the `git` stuff - this may be the solution you are looking for;).

Comment: Thanks again! While I can modify projectB, I'd rather not to introduce a dependency on projectA. There may be multiple independent projectA's by multiple people. I think this can be easily solved by doing an conditional "include" in projectB's build.sbt of a git-ignored file which people can edit on their own desire. Let me test this.

Comment: Apparently, including other SBT files from within an SBT file is non-trivial. I haven't found a solution on the Internet. However, thirstycrow has posted [a working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55107829/603003) in the meanwhile solving the actual root cause. Still, your two answers might be beneficial for other visitors :)